# A simple proof for vector space of continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Since my math skill/knowledge is limited (basic real analysis, linear algebra etc.) and I can only follow proofs based on this knowledge, I am looking for a simple proof of the following claim:

Let $C([a,b],\mathbb{R})$ denote the set of all of continuous real-valued functions defined on the interval $[a,b]$. This vector space has no finite basis.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a basis of cardinal $n$, if you take any $m>n$ elements, they are linearly dependent. So to prove that it has no finite basis, you can simply prove you have an infinite set of linearly independent elements. Can you think of such a set?

> Hint: think about polynomials.

-

> $\forall k\in \Bbb N,e_k = x\mapsto x^n\in \mathcal C^0 \left([a,b],\Bbb R\right)$. Can you prove they are linearly independent?

-

> Let $l \in \Bbb N$ and $\alpha_0,\dots,\alpha_l \in \Bbb R$ so that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^l \alpha_k e_k = \Bbb 0$
>  $\forall x \in \Bbb R, \sum\limits_{k=0}^l \alpha_k x^k=0$
>  Let $I=\{j \in \{0,\dots,l\}, \alpha_j \not = 0\}$
>  Suppose $I\not= \emptyset$
>  Let $d=\max I$
>  $\forall x \in \Bbb R^*, \sum\limits_{k=0}^d \alpha_k x^k=0$ and $\alpha_d \not= 0$
>  So $\sum\limits_{k=0}^d \alpha_k x^{k-d}=0$
>  So $\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty}\sum\limits_{k=0}^d \alpha_k x^{k-d}=0$
>  So $0+\dots+0+\alpha_d = 0$ which is absurd so $I=\emptyset$
>  So $\forall i \in \{0,\dots,l\}, \alpha_i=0$